# lifecycle react , redux, and redux-form apollo-graphql

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have a redux-form component and another container component that load apollo graphql data. Here below just some important parts of code.

FORM COMPONENT:

```
class Form extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    setTimeout(function() {
      this.executeCode ( 'onChangeInput', { action: 'initForm' , props: this.props, formProps: this.props, formState: this.state  });
    }.bind(this), 1000);
  }
  render() {
     (...)
  }
}
const ComponentWithData = reduxForm({
  form: nameForm, 
  validate,
})(Form);

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  const log = false;
  const statesReturn = { myState: state };
  let initialValues;
  initialValues = processValues(ownProps, tableCrud, ownProps.data, 'toClient','view' );
  statesReturn.initialValues = initialValues ;
  return statesReturn;
}

const ComponentWithDataAndState = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  null,
)(ComponentWithData);

export default ComponentWithDataAndState;
```

CONTAINER COMPONENT:

```
class FormContainer extends Component {

  render() {


    const { t, ...otherProps} = this.props;
    let aElements = [];
    let aQlFiltered = {"crud_view_payment":{"table":"payment"}}; 
    const resultCheck = checkLoadCrud (aQlFiltered,this.props);
    if (resultCheck.messageError) {
      return <MsgError msg={resultCheck.messageError} t={this.props.t} />;
    }

    if (!resultCheck.globalLoading && !resultCheck.messageError) {
      if (this.props['crud_view_'+tableCrud] && this.props['crud_view_'+tableCrud][tableCrud]) {
        if (this.props['crud_view_'+tableCrud][tableCrud].deleted) {
    aElements.push(<RecordHeadInfo  
      key="recordhead"
      tableCrud={tableCrud} 
      {...this.props} 
      data={this.props['crud_view_'+tableCrud][tableCrud]} 
      />);
        }
      }
    }

    if (!resultCheck.globalLoading && !resultCheck.messageError) {
      aElements.push(<Form
        crudAction="View"
        key="mainform"
        id={ this.props.match.params.id }
      data={this.props['crud_view_'+tableCrud][tableCrud]}
        onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
        containerPropsForm={this.props}
        t={this.props.t}
      />);
    }


    }
    return (
      <div>
        {aElements}
      </div>
    );

  }
}



const withGraphqlandRouter = compose(

  graphql(defQls.payment.View, {
    name: 'crud_view_payment',
    options: props => {
      const optionsValues = { variables: {id: props.match.params.id, _qlType: 'View' }};
      optionsValues.fetchPolicy = Tables[tableCrud].fetchPolicy ? Tables[tableCrud].fetchPolicy :'network-only';
      return optionsValues;
    },
  }),
)(withRouter(FormContainer));


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    myState: state,
  };
};


const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return bindActionCreators ({ appSubmitStart,  appSubmitStop, showConfirm, initialize, dispatch }, dispatch );  // to set this.props.dispatch
};

const withState = connect(
  mapStateToProps ,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(withGraphqlandRouter);



const ComponentFull = withState; 

export default ComponentFull;
```

on Form Component I have a setTimeout that execute a code, because I need set disable or hidden field accord to data loaded. I can't do it directly on construct() neither componentDidMount() because if i try to retrieve data from redux: this.props.myState.form ( have no values). it's for that use a timeout, with 1000 is ok, and with 1 milisecond it's ok too, I see this.props.myState.form.myForm.values (with data retrivied from db trough apollo), i prefer 1 milisecond of course because i don't see blink fields that get disabled or dissapears, but i'm not sure that is a good practice, because in a slow computer or slow browser that can produce conflict with the render ?

It's not clear form the lifecycle mixing react, redux, apollo and redux-form; anyone has idea how i can order better my ideas to write better code here?

Comment: Your question is noisy, may i suggest to split it in more focused questions ?

Comment: From what i think, you try to merge older code to react with no react understanding. I believe you should not use a let aElements but react state and rendering you elements on state change. Your code create complexity, try to keep it simple and implement piece by piece. Also redux form handleSubmit is an higher order function that pass res as the form result to its first function argument which is your actual handler.

Comment: my question is not about render, but lifecycile, aElements was an advise from an expert in rect like a clean way to render conditional elements. React only is simple, but Reac was made to manage complex scenaries , so my question is just to try describe les cycles, it's a question only to people who had worked with redux , redux form and apollo client.

Comment: I do, use a map of a state property to render multiple elements. About lifecycle, you  should know that your component will not rerender util props or state change or you call forceUpdate.so changing the value of your let will have no effect on your ui.Also, react don't like reassignation. What is your own level to qualify anyone of an expert ? I don't know the guy's real level but don't try to go on the experts things if you are not.